# ssh-copy-id to add key restrictions

Tags: git, security, ssh

In [chapter 4](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) of the **Pro Git** book we learn how to prevent people with SSH access to the `git` user to have a shell session. Then the text proceeds to warn that:

> At this point, users are still able to use SSH port forwarding to access any host the git server is able to reach. If you want to prevent that, you can edit the authorized_keys file and prepend the following options to each key you’d like to restrict:
> `no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty`

Is it possible to have `ssh-copy-id` prepend this to the public key?

Looking at the command options, it looks like `-o ssh_option` might be the place to have the restrictions added to the key, but I could not find any example to show if and how it is used for this use case.

`ssh-copy-id [-f] [-n] [-i identity file] [-p port] [-o ssh_option] [user@]hostname`

Comment: `-o` is for passing options to the `ssh`/`scp` process that transfers the file, not options to add to the remote `.authorized_keys` file along with the key.

Comment: @chepner so it is hopeless, right? I am not sure SSH Academy is an authoritative source or not, anyways, [the page](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id) they have about `ssh-copy-id` says _"The copy-id tool does not automatically add command restrictions to keys."_ Not adding the restrictions *automatically*, implied to me the command could be crafted to have that happen, but this is not the default behavior.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` seems like the wrong tool for this: it requires that you have ssh shell access to `[user@]hostname` so that you can add an authorized key to `[user@]hostname`'s `.ssh/authorized_keys`. To use this to add someone's ssh key to `git@hostname`'s authorized keys, they'd need ssh shell access to `git@hostname` in the first place. (The idea behind ssh-copy-id is that you do it once to install a *new* key, which you'll use from now on, before you switch *to* that new key.)